# Modify hosts file on Android without rooting device

Tags: vpn, hosts

Is it possible to add entry to hosts file on Android without rooting phone?

I am contractor working in remote and I have to use AirWatch and Cisco AnyConnect to get access to VPN, but if I root Samsung tablet (SM-T700, 5.0.2) then I can't get access to VPN. All what I actually need is to access web application behind that VPN with either Firefox or Chrome. It's just adding: ip.ip.ip.ip jbossWorker100.intranetOfCompany.com

I already rooted tablet, changed host file, but then I can't get access VPN, and if I unroot it then I can get through VPN but I can't get to the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. You can, however, run your own DNS server on a local network, that could emulate this behaviour on all appliances that are connected via it.

Comment: We don't have local DNS server on our LAN, so maybe I should check if ruter has that capability?

Comment: That should work.

Comment: @mikky Could you provide a link to a reliable way to run a local DNS server? And could this be used if you're only internet is through wifi tethering?